# whats the best way to store and query invoice data and accounts data?

Tags: php, mysql, invoice, accounts

I am creating a project that will manage many aspects of a business but I am currently writing the invoicing, estimating and credits sections.
I am using php and mysqli,
my front end for this section is well under way but before I get too deep and in a hole i could do with a little input. 
Eg my invoice, estimates and credits data is separated in my db I have inv and invlines tables for invoices, est and est lines for estimates and cred and credlines for credits, the fields for each are identical allowing the reuse of scripts by just switching tables depening on types etc.
my inv table stores the inv number, customer id, customer details invoice date net totals, vat amount and total amount etc and the invlines stores the invref, product number, prod description, cost price net sell price, vat rate, qty etc
in this instance I AM storing calculated values here and there to ensure UK VAT compliance.

Ok so when I arrive at beta stage I will need to be able to produce reports on things like stock movements, vat charged between dates analysis by nominal codes (in invlines tables) and profit and loss (purchase accounts side not started yet) and so on

I figure that my db structure will allow me to query and build that info from what i have stored but my question is do i need to break down this further at point of invoice to speed up reporting. for example on invoice creation, should i also write the vat amount charged to  a vat control table? and if i do that should i also write the stock movement to a stock control table showing when, how many where to where from etc?
this could literally go on for ever double writing everything in a transaction.

As a foot note my db is designed for muiti businesses as each line in each table has an indexed field called coid which holds a reference that is unique to that company and my scripts check that that company can only access its own data.

Thanks in advance Nick

Comment: You could use. Mysql databases and if you want you could back it up in a plain txt file

Answer (score -1):

First: You should never save redundant data in a database. If information can be easily retrieved from the original data, why save it in a cache column? This brings in the problem that the cache value might be wrong! Which is what nobody wants.

Keeping this in mind there are always exceptions to the rule. Some values are really hard to compute and it therefore might be necessary to cache those. This is most likely not the case here.

Another exception is something which one could name (a bit overdrawing) "data warehousing". There are e.g. legal requirements to keep invoices at hand for a long period of time. This data is likely not to change anymore (it's history, so what should change?) and it may be a requirement to be able to output the data as it was on that specific day in the past at any time in the future. This exception might apply to your case!

If this really applies to you, I cannot decide based on the information you provided. You have to find out yourself or provide detailed information (but this might exceed the frame of a SO question), but I hope I could give you some direction what to think of.

Comment: so what you are saying is that if for example I wanted a report on vat invoiced between 01/01/2014 and 31/01/2014 it would be acceptable to query something like Select vatamount from inv where invdate BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2 AND coid = $this company id then add thenm in a while loop to give a total vat received?, ((see Next))

Comment: ok i can see this would be efficient as i have stored the calculated values for each whole invoice in inv record, but would this be acceptable performance wise when i need to track stock movements by checking each line of each invoice between theses dates (there could be tens of thousands) the coid index will help with speed but each part number would need to run through a function to match to a products database to see if its a stored part or one off added part. Although  i am finding mysql keeps surprising me in its speed.

Comment: Sorry, but it is really hard to follow here without knowing what exactly you want to do and without seeing any database schema... do you have a fairly good understanding of JOINs and indices? Most computations can be made very efficiently in a relational database! What I would cache redundantly would be e.g. the applied VAT. Then I would not need to keep track of changing VATs and this is something which will never change in the future. I unfortunately did not understand your thoughts concerning stock movements. What have stocks to do with invoices or estimates? Cannot help this way.